# Why does Android crash when stressed on Memory where as GNU-Linux keeps running?

Tags: linux, memory, android, crash

I have two devices, an Android phone with an eGlibC stack running side by side with Bionic, and an old HP tower with Debian.

My HP tower has 512 MB of RAM.

My phone has 2GB of RAM.

I run top on both to keep an eye on things. I have been compiling stuff on my phone, well because the phone it's self has better specs than my HP tower and I am studying ARM assembly, so working on ARM makes sense, at least to me.

My tower is pretty much always tight on memory usually with about 20 MB of free ram at any given point in time, sometimes less depending on what I am doing. My tower has been up and running for 40 days:

```
$uptime
17:34:14 up 40 days,  8:54, 12 users,  load average: 2.60, 2.14, 1.58
```

But, my phone, running Android, which is supposed to be designed for low memory environments, crashes when I push it to about 50MB of free memory, this has happened more often now that I am compiling larger projects such as the Android SDK/NDK .

- Why is this?
- What could be some possibilities? I would like to fix the problem but reading over every bit of code in the Android project is infeasible .
- Where should I start?

Comment: What does `swapon -s` say on each system? Maybe the HP has more swap space.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been busy, My HP has 1073148 KiB of swap, my Android device has 1919996 KiB of swap. I have a dedicated 2GB SD card for swap on my phone. Would the C libraries affect memory management in the kernel?